# Why Bootstrap 4.5 showing bold font for entire component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am using `Bootstrap 4.5.2` for my angular application. In my `DashboardComponent` all font showing bold.

This is my code `DashboardComponent`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/themes/prism.css" /> -->

    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>
 
 <style>

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
}
</style>

<main class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">                   
          <div style="border: none;margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 25px;">          
            <ul class="list-group .list-group-flush borderless">

              <li style="border: none; height: 47px; background-color: #f5f5f5;" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                Relay Server
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
              </li>
              <li style="border: none;  height: 47px; background-color: #f5f5f5;" class="list-group-item borderless">St</li>               
            </ul>
          </div> -->

        </div>   
     </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- 15-->
      <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 20px;" class="col-md-4 card card-body bg-light align-items-center">

        <div>
          <p class="lead text-left">Build Status</p>
          <canvas id="chBar" width="350" height="240"></canvas>
        </div>    
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stackedbar</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/themes/prism.css" /> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/themes/prism.css" />

      <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This how text is looking

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing these references from `index.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.16.0/themes/prism.css" />  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```